# $a,b\in\Bbb R$ $a\cdot b=6$ $\;\min(2a+3b)=?$

Tags: calculus

> $a,b\in \Bbb R$
>
> $a\cdot b=6$
>
> $\min(2a+3b)=?$

My Solution:

Substituted $b=\frac{6}{a}$ into $2a+3b$ and took the derivative to determine the minimum point, I got:

$$2-\frac{18}{a^2}=0$$

$$(a_1,b_1)=(-3,-2) \ \ , (a_2,b_2)=(3,2) $$

When these values are plugged in, I get $-12$ as the minimum value of $2a+3b$. But, when I plug in $(-1,-6)$ for $(a,b)$, I get even lower value of $-20$.

The answer is given as $-12$, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your function is effectively $2a + \frac{18}{a}$. If $a$ is allowed to be any (non-zero) real number, then this has no minimum since it approaches $-\infty$ as $a\to -\infty$. The points you found by setting the derivative to $0$ are a *local* minimum and *local* maximum. [Here](http://wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+2a+%2B+18%2Fa) is a graph of the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The minimum does not exist.

Try $a\rightarrow-\infty$ and $b=\frac{6}{a}.$

If $a$ and $b$ are integers, so $ab=6$ gives 
$$(a,b)\in\{(1,6),(2,3),(3,2),(6,1),(-1,-6),(-2,-3),(-3,-2),(-6,-1)\}$$
and you can choose the answer.

By the way, if $a$ and $b$ are positives then by AM-GM we obtain:
$$2a+3b\geq2\sqrt{2a\cdot3b}=2\sqrt{6ab}=12.$$

Comment: $a,b$ are said to be reals.

Comment: @Yves Daoust See please a first line of my post. In the rest I tried to understand what is a meaning.

Answer (score 1):

**Graphical method.** You can draw the constraint curves ($b=\frac 6a$) and contour lines ($b=-\frac 23a+\frac c3$):

[image: ![enter image description here]

As contour line shifts lower (blue, red, green, violet lines), it still intersects the constraint black curve (i.e. the constraint is satisfied), hence there is no minimum of $c=2a+3b$.

But if $a,b>0$, then the minimum of $c=2a+3b$ is achieved at the point $A(3,2)$, that is $c(3,2)=2\cdot 3+3\cdot 2=12$ is minimum.

Answer (score 0):

**My solution:**

Let $c:=2a+3b$ and eliminate $b$. We have

$$c=2a+\frac{18}a$$ and

$$\frac{dc}{da}=2-\frac{18}a^2=0$$ or $$a=\pm3,$$ which determines the stationary points $c=\pm12$.

$c=12$ is a local minimum (and $c=-12$ a local maximum), but as the function is unbounded near $a=0$, there is no global minimum.

Comment: Actually, a local minimum of a function  it's not a minimum of the function. They are two different things.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg: we know that, why this comment ?

Comment: If we know this, why you wrote about the local minimum?

Comment: Because the lowest local minimum can be the global maximum, don't you know ? And this echoes the questioning of the OP.

Comment: I'm confused over why $\frac{dc}{da}$ is not $2-\frac{18}{a^2}=0$ and $a=\pm3$ as in my solution? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @EldarRahimli: my bad.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg: I think that you don't like my comments.